# Can't find derivative of function in Stewart's calculus book on a lesson concerning shapes of graphs/ curve sketching

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I was studying and encountered this example which asks you to find the derivative and second derivative of
$$y=x^{2/3}(6-x)^{1/3}$$

The first derivative then would be
$$f^{'}(x)=\frac{4-x}{x^{1/3}(6-x)^{2/3}}$$

Which is what I got and what's written in the book

Then the second derivative
$$f^{''}(x)=\frac{-8}{x^{4/3}(6-x)^{5/3}}$$

Is given in the book but I failed to calculate it myself. I've already tried four times using the quotient rule for the function as is given, using logarithmic differentiation, rewriting the fraction as a product of and using the product rule, and rewriting $f^{'}(x)$ as $(g(x))^{1/3}$ and using the chain rule. I tried https://www.derivative-calculator.net/ but it shows the simplified form without showing the calculations. I suspect this to be an elementary algebra mistake on my part. At this point I'm desperate and hopeless. Please show me the differentiation and simplification process of finding the second derivative.

Edit: I solved it. Turns out I missed a minus sign.

Comment: Try re-writing as $(4-x)x^{-1/3}(6-x)^{-2/3}$ then use the triple product rule $(fgh)' = f'gh+fg'h+fgh'$.

Comment: @B.Goddard I already tried that. from post: I've already tried... rewriting the fraction as a product of and using the product rule.

Comment: I might try calculating $f'(x)^3$, simplifying, then take the cube root again.

Comment: You might also try the substitution $x=u^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:
$$y^3=x^2(6-x)\implies3y^2y'=12x-3x^2$$
$$\implies6yy'^2+3y^2y''=12-6x$$
But, $$y'^2=\frac{x^2(4-x)^2}{y^4}$$
So,
$$\frac{6x^2(4-x)^2}{y^3}+3y^2y''=6(2-x)$$
$$\implies3y^2y''=6(2-x)-\frac{6(4-x)^2}{6-x}=\frac{-24}{6-x}$$
And $$y^2=x^{\frac43}(6-x)^{\frac23}$$
Hence$$y''=\frac{-8}{3x^{\frac43}(6-x)^{\frac53}}$$

Comment: I'll accept this but I think you meant to say $3y^{2}y^{''}=\frac{-24}{6-x}$

Comment: yes you are right! Thanks